# Filter column based on an already filter column

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to get your help, I would like to Filter the values of Column A from Worksheet "Parts status" based on the values filtered on an Activesheet.

Using this code it always filter on "Parts status" all values from the active sheet and i just want to filter based on the filtered ones.

Can you please tell me where is the mistake on my code?

```
Sub FilterTest1()

    Dim RngOne As Range, cell As Range
    Dim arrList() As String, lngCnt As Long
    
    With ActiveSheet
        Set RngOne = .Range("A6:A500")
    End With
    
    'load values into an array
    lngCnt = 0
    
    For Each cell In RngOne
        ReDim Preserve arrList(lngCnt)
        arrList(lngCnt) = cell.Text
        lngCnt = lngCnt + 1
    Next
    
    With Sheets("Parts Status")
        If .FilterMode Then .ShowAllData
        .Range("A11:A1000").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=arrList, Operator:=xlFilterValues
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Is your `ActiveSheet` already filtered? Although I would suggest not to use `ActiveSheet`. You should try and always qualify your sheets

Comment: Because i want this code to several worksheets, and to not keep modifying (Personalize) the code i want to use "ActiveSheet". but still..following your idea. I have the column A of an activesheet with values fitered and i want that values be filtered on the column A of another worksheet and not full column even showing the filtered values

Comment: When you set your range as: `Set RngOne = .Range("A6:A500")`, it takes every cell in that range. If you have a filter on the range then look into `Range.SpecialCells`. That will give you your filtered cells which you can then use to set your array and use that array as your criteria

Comment: So how it would be? Set RngOne = .Range.SpecialCells("A6:A500")?

Comment: it should be: `Set RngOne = .Range("A6:A500").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`

Comment: no problem. Glad it helped

Comment: Zac, last question, i have Range of cells with formula and i would like to highlight them when they change the value(higher) for a period of 12h, i tried a code with timer but that blocked me the workbook and i could not work on the file.

Comment: :) as this is a completely new question, please ask a new question. I will post my answer as answer so that you can accept it and close this question

Answer (score 0):

> Set RngOne = .Range("A6:A500").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)